# tinybutstrong xlsx autamatic ope=xlsxNum

Tags: format, cell, numeric, xlsx, tinybutstrong

Is there is any way to make TBS automaticly choose when cell need to be numeric (ope=xlsxNum)? Or is it posible to use if or when for ope?

Comment: Can you give details of the case you have? Why the cell should contains several type of data ? What kind of "if" to you wish for parameter ope?

Comment: [DATA.name;block=c;if DATA.type=NUM;ope=xlsxNum]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tip and trick that should work.

The difficulty is that in case of MergeBlock, formating parameters such as "ope=xlsxNum" are processed before the data are injected. This is for performance consideration.
So we are going to merge the data twice: one for preparing TBS fields for the formating, and a second one for actually injecting data using MergeField() instead of MergeBlock().

Here is an example of data as a PHP array:

```
$data = array(
    array('name'=>"Nom",    'type'=>'STR', 'value'=>'Jack');
    array('name'=>"Stock",  'type'=>'NUM', 'value'=>1305);
    array('name'=>"Value",  'type'=>'NUM', 'value'=>1.5498888);
);
```

Put the follong snippet in the cell:

```
[b2.[b1.$;block=c].value;[b1.type;if '[val]'='NUM';then 'ope=xlsxNum'; else '']]
```

And at the PHP side:

```
$TBS->MergeBlock('b1', $data); // prepare TBS fields with corresponding formating
$TBS->MergeField('b2', $data); // merge TBS fields with corresponding data
```

After 'b1' is merged, the template becomes:

```
[b2.0.value;] | [b2.0.value;ope=xlsxNum] | [b2.0.value;ope=xlsxNum]
```

After 'b2' is merged, the template becomes:

```
Jack | 1305 | 1.5498888
```